# How can I apply a curve fitting function over different columns' levels in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, curve-fitting, nls

Given the data frame `df`:

```
(time <- rep(c(1:9),9))
(test <- rep(c(1:3),3, each = 9))
(specie <- rep(c("Lbcasei", "Lbparacasei", "Lbrhamnosus"), each = 27))

(OD <- rep(c(runif(4,min=0, max=0.4),
                 runif(1,min=0.4, max=0.6),
                 runif(4,min=0.6, max=1)),
               9))
df <- data.frame(specie, test, time, OD)
```

and given the rquisite function `curve_func`:

```
curve_func <- function(t, A, B, C){B / (1 + exp(-C * (t - A))) }
```

I want apply the following curve fitting function `fit` , which uses as input `OD` values over time points `time` :

```
fit <- nls(OD ~ growth_func(time, A, B, C), start = list(A = min(time), B = max(OD), C = 0.05))
```

over all the levels of `specie` and `test` columns.

Can anybody help suggesting a function or any other way to iterate/loop it?

I went through the function of the Tidyverse, in particular dplyr,tidyr and purrr, but I did not find specific functions for my problem.

Also, I tried to dig into the theory behind Iteration in R, mainly following the guide [RforDataScience](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#iteration), but I did not succeed in that.
Thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- when using random numbers use `set.seed` first to make the result reproducible.  We do so in the Note at the end.  Also we make `specie` a factor.
- the structure of the data is such that the data values for each `specie` value is the same so the parameters for the 3 values of `specie` will be the same and we can ignore the grouping.  We do show without grouping and with.
- use nls2 to get initial values
- the name of the curve/growth function must correspond to the definition.  We have corrected this.

**1)** Initial values and fit all ungrouped code--

```
library(nls2)

curve_func <- function(t, A, B, C){B / (1 + exp(-C * (t - A))) }


fit0 <- nls2(OD ~ curve_func(time, A, B, C), 
            df,
            start = data.frame(A = range(df$time), B = range(df$OD), C = 0:1),
            alg = "brute")
co <- as.list(coef(fit0))

fit1 <- nls(OD ~ curve_func(time, A, B, C), 
           df,
           start = list(A = co$A, B = co$B, C = co$C))
fit1
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: OD ~ curve_func(time, A, B, C)
##    data: df
##      A      B      C 
## 5.3398 1.0203 0.7857 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 1.267
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 17 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.615e-06
```

**2)** This shows how to specify distinct groups although it is not needed with this data due to the fact that the groups, hence the parameters, are the same.  We use `co` from above for initial values.

```
k <- nlevels(df$specie)
levels(df$specie)
## [1] "Lbcasei"     "Lbparacasei" "Lbrhamnosus"

fit2 <- nls(OD ~ curve_func(time, A[specie], B[specie], C[specie]), 
           df,
           start = list(A = rep(co$A, k), B = rep(co$B, k), C = rep(co$C, k)))
fit2
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: OD ~ curve_func(time, A[specie], B[specie], C[specie])
##    data: df
##     A1     A2     A3     B1     B2     B3     C1     C2     C3 
## 5.3398 5.3398 5.3398 1.0203 1.0203 1.0203 0.7857 0.7857 0.7857 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 1.267
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 17 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.608e-06
```

Since the fit1 and fit2 models are the same, i.e. they give the same predictions, we get a p value of 1 when comparing them using `anova` in this case.

```
anova(fit1, fit2)
## Analysis of Variance Table
##
## Model 1: OD ~ curve_func(time, A, B, C)
## Model 2: OD ~ curve_func(time, A[specie], B[specie], C[specie])
##   Res.Df Res.Sum Sq Df Sum Sq F value Pr(>F)
## 1     78     1.2674                         
## 2     72     1.2674  6      0       0      1
```

**3) nlme** Another way to get grouped values is to use `nlsList` in nlme.  This package comes with R so it does not have to be installed, only loaded with a `library` statement.  `co` is from above.

```
library(nlme)

fit3 <- nlsList(OD ~ curve_func(time, A, B, C) | specie, 
           df,
           start = list(A = co$A, B = co$B, C = co$C))
fit3
## Call:
##   Model: OD ~ curve_func(time, A, B, C) | specie 
##    Data: df 
##
## Coefficients:
##                    A       B        C
## Lbcasei     5.339834 1.02033 0.785739
## Lbparacasei 5.339834 1.02033 0.785739
## Lbrhamnosus 5.339834 1.02033 0.785739
##
## Degrees of freedom: 81 total; 72 residual
## Residual standard error: 0.1326762
```

**4)** Another way is to use `Map` and the `subset=` argument of `nls`.  `co` is from above.  The result is a named list of `nls` objects.

```
fit4 <- Map(function(x) {
  nls(OD ~ curve_func(time, A, B, C), 
      df,
      start = list(A = co$A, B = co$B, C = co$C),
      subset = specie == x)
}, levels(df$specie))
```

### Note

Same as question except `set.seed` added and `specie` is a factor.

```
set.seed(13)
(time <- rep(c(1:9),9))
(test <- rep(c(1:3),3, each = 9))
(specie <- rep(c("Lbcasei", "Lbparacasei", "Lbrhamnosus"), each = 27))

(OD <- rep(c(runif(4,min=0, max=0.4),
                 runif(1,min=0.4, max=0.6),
                 runif(4,min=0.6, max=1)),
               9))
df <- data.frame(specie = factor(specie), test, time, OD)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your prompt suggestions!